# JSTL Tag variables inside another variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, jspx

Basically, I'm trying to do this: `${ ${var} }`.

I have the following:

```
<c:set var="x1" value="value1"/>
<c:set var="value1" value="x2"/>
```

My goal is to use `x1` to get `x2`. At runtime, I do not know `value1`. So, my first guess is that `${ ${x1} }` = `${ value1 }` = `x2`. However, this does not work. How do I accomplish this task? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding why and when this should be useful, but I think `${pageScope[x1]}` should work.

`${}` means interpret the JSP EL expression inside the curly braces. And `${}` is not a JSP EL operator, so it can't be used inside `${}`.